# PHP Script not found : GET Http://localhost4200/contact/sendmail.php 404 (Not Found)

Tags: php, angular, angular-services

I have an Angular 5 app that I want to run locally before attempting to deploy it on Internet.

I have a `contact` component in order to receive email from Users via a contact form. In the component folder I have a PHP script `sendmail.php` that is called when I click on my form button.

Here is the global structure :

```
MyProjectName
----- src
----- ----- app
----- ----- ----- contact
----- ----- ----- ----- contact.component.html
----- ----- ----- ----- contact.component.scss
----- ----- ----- ----- contact.component.spec.ts
----- ----- ----- ----- contact.component.ts
----- ----- ----- ----- sendmail.php
```

In the `contact.component.html` I call a function `sendEmail()` on the click :

```
contact.html

    <button type="submit" (click)="sendEmail()">Send</button>
```

Here is the function in the `contact.component.ts` file

```
export class ContactComponent implements OnInit {

     constructor(private sendMailService:SendMailService) { }

     sendEmail():void {
          this.sendMailService.performGetEx().subscribe();
     }
```

And the service `send-mail.service.ts`that call the php script. This service is located at the same level as the `contact` folder ***and it seems that the error on the path occurs here***

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import {HttpClient, HttpHeaders} from '@angular/common/http';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs';

@Injectable()
export class SendMailService {

constructor(private http:HttpClient) { }

performGetEx():Observable<any> {
     return this.http.get<any>('./contact/sendmail.php');
}
```

Each Time I click on my form button here is the Error :

> GET http://localhost:4200/contact/sendmail.php 404 (Not Found)    zone.js:2935
>
> ERROR HttpErrorResponse {headers: HttpHeaders, status: 404, statusText: "Not 
>     Found", url: "http://localhost:4200/contact/sendmail.php", ok: false, …}

Is it really a path Error ? is Angular Cli server able to get php script ?

**UPDATE :**

I deployed my Angular project with Wamp Server ( By the way all my style are KO I don't know if it's normal ?) and I wasn't able to call my script on the click until I added the `action` property on my form :

```
contact.component.html

<form action= "sendmail.php" method="post">
...
</form>
```

I did the same without Wamp and I have the same issue.